# PHP: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, cs-cart

If I remove this code everything works fine, but I need to loop over the products from the data (serialized) received.  When I use this code it breaks and I don't know why.

```
$products = db_query("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
//fn_print_die($products);
$products = unserialize($products);
$shippingCost = db_get_field("SELECT shipping FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
$tax = db_get_field("SELECT tax FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
$orderTotal = db_get_field("SELECT order_total FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
$email = db_get_field("SELECT email FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);

$sum=0;
//echo $products;
if (!empty($products)) {

  foreach ($products as $product) {
    $text .='
      <tr>
        <td><a  href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'?dispatch=products.view&product_id='.$product['product_id'].'"> <img title="" height="120" width="120" alt="" src="'.$product['main_pair']['detailed']['image_path'].'"></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['product'].'</a><a href="#">&nbsp;<i></i></a><div style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;"> CODE: <span>'.$product['product_code'].'<!--product_code_update_2512012004--></span> </div></td>
        <td style=" text-align:center;"><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">$</span><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['price'].'</span> </td>
        <td><div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;width: 56px;"><input type="text" disabled value="'.$product['amount'].'" size="3"  style="border:1px solid #c2c9d0; box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; border-radius:3px; float: left;height: 33px;text-align: center;width: 36px;"></div></td>
        <td style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:bold; color:#333; text-align:center; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;"><span>$</span><span stye=" color:#000;">'.$product['price']*$product['amount'].'</span> </td>
      </tr>';
    $sum =$sum+$product['price']*$product['amount'];
  }
}
```

In log:

> [Mon Feb 08 03:59:42 2016] [error] [client 90.199.142.58] PHP Warning:  unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/addons/abandoned_cart_extended/controllers/backend/ac.php on line 24, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

It's literally the unserialize that breaks.  I've tried removing just that part, and the rest works.  It's 4am now, and I need to get this working before 9am when I need to be in the office.

Comment: error message seems clear to me

Comment: maybe to you haha but im so new to PHP not sure how to amend to resolve it :(

Comment: `db_query` is not a php core function, so no idea what it is doing. `var_dump($products)` should tell you more

Comment: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/core/db/placeholders.html

Comment: Try `$products = db_get_field("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);`

Comment: 2 secs, ill give it a go

Comment: nothing, i added: fn_print_die($products); after it and nothing worked bt got in response: http://pastebin.com/SmPZiKFn

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = db_query("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
```

`$products` is an object you first need to fetch the cart value in a variable and pass that to `unserialize` method, assuming  you are using mysqli you can try like this

```
if( $products->num_rows > 0 ){
    $data = $products->fetch_assoc();

    $products = unserialize($row['cart']);

    $shippingCost = db_get_field("SELECT shipping FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
    $tax = db_get_field("SELECT tax FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
    $orderTotal = db_get_field("SELECT order_total FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
    $email = db_get_field("SELECT email FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);

    $sum=0;
    //echo $products;
    if (!empty($products)) {

      foreach ($products as $product) {
        $text .='
          <tr>
            <td><a  href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'?dispatch=products.view&product_id='.$product['product_id'].'"> <img title="" height="120" width="120" alt="" src="'.$product['main_pair']['detailed']['image_path'].'"></a></td>
            <td><a href="#" style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['product'].'</a><a href="#">&nbsp;<i></i></a><div style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;"> CODE: <span>'.$product['product_code'].'<!--product_code_update_2512012004--></span> </div></td>
            <td style=" text-align:center;"><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">$</span><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['price'].'</span> </td>
            <td><div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;width: 56px;"><input type="text" disabled value="'.$product['amount'].'" size="3"  style="border:1px solid #c2c9d0; box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; border-radius:3px; float: left;height: 33px;text-align: center;width: 36px;"></div></td>
            <td style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:bold; color:#333; text-align:center; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;"><span>$</span><span stye=" color:#000;">'.$product['price']*$product['amount'].'</span> </td>
          </tr>';
        $sum =$sum+$product['price']*$product['amount'];
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: it does use mysqli yes, shall i change the query and place that inside the foreach? sorry im very new to this.

Comment: @James after fetching values using `fetch_assoc() or fetch_array()` you can use that in loop. After this statement `$products = unserialize($row['cart']);` print the values `print_r($products);` to check you're getting the required values or not

Comment: I gave this a go: http://pastebin.com/BXgUArWa but got: [Mon Feb 08 04:40:17 2016] [error] [client 90.199.142.58] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/addons/abandoned_cart_extended/controllers/backend/ac.php on line 25, referer: admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

Comment: I guess `db_get_field()` is your custom method defined to fetch the values from the query result. In that case you `$products` is already an associative array now, so you will no longer need to use `$data = $products->fetch_assoc();`, remove that statement and try this `$products = unserialize($products['cart']);` instead of `$products = unserialize($row['cart']);`

Comment: I just done that and think done correctly, i done a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/7U6h98s3 however i tried the request and response was empty with no error in php log

Comment: I done a fn_print_die($products); before $sum and returned in console: false

Comment: What is the output of this `print_r($products);` before this condition `if (!empty($products)) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102868/discussion-between-james-and-haridarshan).

Answer (score 0):

```
unserialize in php needs a string and your $product variable was interpreted in php as an object.
```

Thats how the error came out.

> unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string

you can check what is the returned value of $products by using print_r or var_dump to confirm that it is an Object and not a string.

```
$products = db_query("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
print_r($products);
```

I dont see the point of using [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) since in the code you posted you haven't use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

From the documenation of [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

> unserialize() takes a single serialized variable and converts it back
>   into a PHP value.

Means that you should have used [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) before using [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert it back in a PHP value.

**UPDATED**

try using db_get_array()

```
 $products = db_get_array("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
//now you can use $products as an array format
if (!empty($products)) {

  foreach ($products as $product) {
    $text .='
      <tr>
        <td><a  href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'?dispatch=products.view&product_id='.$product['product_id'].'"> <img title="" height="120" width="120" alt="" src="'.$product['main_pair']['detailed']['image_path'].'"></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['product'].'</a><a href="#">&nbsp;<i></i></a><div style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;"> CODE: <span>'.$product['product_code'].'<!--product_code_update_2512012004--></span> </div></td>
        <td style=" text-align:center;"><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">$</span><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['price'].'</span> </td>
        <td><div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;width: 56px;"><input type="text" disabled value="'.$product['amount'].'" size="3"  style="border:1px solid #c2c9d0; box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; border-radius:3px; float: left;height: 33px;text-align: center;width: 36px;"></div></td>
        <td style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:bold; color:#333; text-align:center; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;"><span>$</span><span stye=" color:#000;">'.$product['price']*$product['amount'].'</span> </td>
      </tr>';
    $sum =$sum+$product['price']*$product['amount'];
  }
}
```

Comment: that stopped breaking of the code, and went through and i got the email but i the email it never showed the products etc... any data from the cart query...

Comment: i used after that query: fn_print_die($products); and got back {"debug_info":[{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}],"notifications":[]}

Comment: Please use `print_r($products)` then update your post with the result of the print_r.So that we can see the output value of $products

Comment: i just added response to comment

Comment: @James is it different result when you use unserialize?

Comment: @James Please use print_r and not fn_print_die

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the standard cs-cart method db_get_field instead of db_query:

```
$products = db_get_field("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
```

Your $products will contains only `cart` field of `abandoned_cart` table. Then you can use this string for unserialize and working with given object as you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming from a Linux/Unix type server and you are running this on a windows server, then it could be due to a integer limitation with PHP on Windows. I had this same problem when setting up a dev environment on a windows box.

[The following is from the php manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on
>   Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit. PHP does not
>   support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the
>   constant PHP_INT_SIZE, maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX
>   since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5, and minimum value using the constant
>   PHP_INT_MIN since PHP 7.0.0.